# Can't click on element. ElementNotInteractable SELENIUM

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on a "next page" button but an "ElementNotInteractable" error appears.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time

options = Options()
options.headless = False
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')

website = 'https://www.promoopcion.com/bebidas/termos.html'
path = '/Users/diegotrigal/OneDrive/00000001_HDD_TOSHIBA/diegotrigal/PYHTON/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options=options)
driver.get(website)
driver.maximize_window()
# driver.implicitly_wait(30)
# driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot-3.png")

# pagination

pagination = driver.find_element('xpath', '//div[contains(@class, "products-list")]')
pages = pagination.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
last_page = 8

current_page = 1

product_name = []
product_sku = []

while current_page <= last_page:
    container = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "products-list")]')
    productos = container.find_elements_by_xpath('.//li')

    for product in productos:
        product_name.append(product.find_element_by_class_name("product-item-name").text)
        product_sku.append(product.find_element_by_class_name("product-sku").text)

        current_page = current_page + 1

        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,2000)')

        try:
            next_page = driver.find_element('xpath', '//li[contains(@class, "pages-item-next")]')
            next_page.click()
        except:
            pass


df_productos = pd.DataFrame({'Nombre': product_name, 'SKU': product_sku})
df_productos.to_csv('termos.csv', index=False)

driver.quit()


# driver.find_element_by_class_name('product-items')
# driver.find_element_by_class_name('product-item-link')
# driver.find_element_by_class_name('product-sku')
```

I'm trying to run it by changing the next_page's xpath to different ones but it doesn't work.

I also try the `is_displayed` condition (once upon the scroll window action is made) and it returns `False`, but `is_enabled()` returns `True`.

Comment: In my limited experience using Selenium I found the `javascriptexecutor` to work more reliably for doing clicks and such as you don't have to contend with the element being visible, etc. [javascript-executor-in-selenium-python](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/javascript-executor-in-selenium-python/)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Take the info of products for every page?

Answer (score 0):

With this script you can get what you want, I hope the comments on code helps:

```
# Needed libs
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

# Initiate the driver and navigate
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.promoopcion.com/bebidas/termos.html?product_list_limit=24')

# We count how many pages we have counting the number of elements that we have for pagination
number_of_pages = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='pages'])[2]//a[@class='page']"))))

# For every number of page we take the titles and then click on next button to go to next page
for i in range(0,number_of_pages):
    product_titles = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='product-item-link']")))
    for product_title in product_titles:
        print(product_title.text)

    next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//a[@title='Siguiente'])[2]")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next_button)
    next_button.click()
    time.sleep(2)

# In this point we are in the last page, so we take the products of last page
product_titles = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='product-item-link']")))
for product_title in product_titles:
    print(product_title.text)
```

Comment: Can you Mark the answer as acceptex if It worked? Thank you!